Applying the MeanFilter function to individual array columns
How can I use the MeanFilter function on only the second or third column of my table?
{{1,2,5},{2,5,6},{3,7,1},{4,3,10},{5,8,7},{6,8,3},{7,8,6},{8,6,6},{9,9,4},{10,1,7}}?
Or do I need to extract the second and third column data into separate lists and only then use it?
Thanks to all.

Do you mean you want to do it "in place"? If so, maybe you want SubsetMap:
data = {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 5, 6}, {3, 7, 1}, {4, 3, 10}, {5, 8, 7}, {6, 8,
3}, {7, 8, 6}, {8, 6, 6}, {9, 9, 4}, {10, 1, 7}};

(* Apply to second column *)
SubsetMap[MeanFilter[#, 1] &, data, {All, 2}]

(* Apply to third column *)
SubsetMap[MeanFilter[#, 1] &, data, {All, 3}]

